# Lights pass through the objects in unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, light, lightning, urp

I'm having a trouble, I'm trying to create a dark scene for my project, but, when I add lights, the lights pass through the objects, it has no sense, becouse it pass through the walls.

Light beside of an object
[image: Light beside of an object]

Light passing through the object
[image: Light passing through the object]

I tried setting my objects to static, but it is not working.

Also I tried setting Bias in my Universal Render Pipeline settings to 0, but, the same.

Comment: Hi Seokku. I think that the issue is essentially about shadow casting. If we want an object to block the light reaching another object, then we essentially want it to cast a shadow (in Unity terms). So it is important that your Lights are set up to support shadows. Also, your Universal Render Pipeline Asset should be configured so that it supports shadows (Lighting->Main Light and Additional Lights). The individual renderers can be configured to not cast shadows, but will be on per default. Some materials won't support shadows - often when rendering with semi-transparency.